# How can I use VBScript to read the attributes of an mp4 file

Tags: vbscript, mp4

I'm trying to make a database of my movie library using VBScript, but I can't figure out how to get the attributes of mp4 files. I used this code in a different [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17945886/how-to-extract-the-properties-of-all-files-and-folders-of-a-particular-directory) for a similar purpose. Here is the code I have so far.

```
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO,objf,objfolder, objFile, strFileProperties, strFiles,OBJFLD,objfile2
dim objf1,objfile1,objtextfile,strfolderproperties,objsubfld,objfl,objfl1,strfileproperties2

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objf= objFSO.Getfolder("E:\Share Drive\Chris\Movies")
set OBJfl=objf.files
for each objfl1 in OBJfl
  'display properties of the files of the main folder   
  strFileProperties2 = strFileProperties2 & "Title: " & objfl1.Name & VbCrLf
  strFileProperties2 = strFileProperties2 & "Size: " & objFl1.Size & " bytes" & VbCrLf
  strFileProperties2 = strFileProperties2 & "Type: " & objFl1.Type & VbCrLf & vbcrlf
next

set objf1=objfso.getfolder("C:\")

set objfile1=objfso.getfile( "C:\database.txt")

set objf1=nothing
set objfile1=nothing

set objtextfile=objfso.opentextfile("C:\database.txt",8,true)

objtextfile.writeline(strfileproperties)
objtextfile.writeline(strfileproperties2)
objtextfile.close

set objf1=objfso.getfolder("C:\")

set objfile1=objfso.getfile( "C:\database.txt")

set objf1=nothing
set objfile1=nothing

set objsubfld=objfso.opentextfile("C:\database.txt",8,true)
objsubfld.writeline(strfolderproperties)
objsubfld.close
```

The other attributes I'd like are frame width, frame height, and length. I've tried `objMp4File.Length` but I get an error saying it's not defined. I'm new to VBScript so I might be going at this the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your OS, for Windows 7 this will work, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787870%28v=vs.85%29.aspx;

```
fname = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 155)
size = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 1)
ftype = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 2)
length = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 27)
frameheight = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 283)
framewidth = objFolder.GetDetailsOf(objFolderItem, 285)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give it a try

```
Option Explicit

Dim shellApplication, folderNamespace

    Set shellApplication = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set folderNamespace  = shellApplication.Namespace("E:\Share Drive\Chris\Movies")

Dim headers, i, aHeaders(290)
    For i = 0 to 289
        aHeaders(i) = folderNamespace.GetDetailsOf(folderNamespace.Items, i)
    Next


Dim fileName    
    For Each fileName in folderNamespace.Items
        If LCase(Right(fileName,4))=".mp4" Then 
            For i = 0 to 289
                Wscript.Echo i & vbtab & aHeaders(i) & ": " & folderNamespace.GetDetailsOf(fileName, i)
            Next
            WScript.Echo "-------------------------------------------------------"
        End If
    Next
```

The set of properties available for each kind of file can and will vary.